Troubleshooting Error When Installing Devtools Package
I am trying to install the devtools package in R (using: install.packages('devtools')) and keep running into this error:
Error installing package 'ps':
==============================

* installing to library 'C:/Users/JBRONSTE/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfH3zZ/renv-staging-13cc5048466c'
* installing *source* package 'ps' ...
** package 'ps' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign   -Wall px.c -o px
make: /mingw64/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makevars:11: px] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ps'
* removing 'C:/Users/JBRONSTE/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfH3zZ/renv-staging-13cc5048466c/ps'
Error: install of package 'ps' failed

What is the best way to troubleshoot this?
I double checked that Rtools is installed for the right version, not sure what else to do as I am a fairly new user and IT people have been unable to assist me.

Since ps is a dependency package, try installing it separately first before installing devtools

And try installing it from binary (precompiled) packages instead of source, try seting up option: `options(pkgType="binary").

If you run the current (major.minor) version of R ie currently R 4.4.1 or 4.4.0 then you get served binaries. You are likely on an older version, and so you to install from source.  Which is generally more work, and more fragile.  To do so, you must install Rtools to obtain the here-missing /mingw64/bin/gcc.  So in short I'd upgrade R.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko I tried that and it worked! Does the binary package type change my project in anyway or do I need to do anything additional after installing the package? Thanks so much!!

No, it doesn't. It's just a binary version of the package, maintained and distributed by CRAN (and other repositories).
